# TCP socket connection in react-native

Tags: react-native, tcp

I want to make a TCP socket connection.

my server code in java.

```
// File Name GreetingServer.java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

 public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException {
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
  serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
  }

   public void run() {
     while(true) {
      try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + 
           serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        
        System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress()
           + "\nGoodbye!");
        server.close();
        
     } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
        break;
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
     }
     }
   }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
     int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     try {
        Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
        t.start();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make a client in react-native .

**Import the library:**

```
import TcpSocket from 'react-native-tcp-socket';
// const net = require('react-native-tcp-socket');
```

**Client**

```
// Create socket
const client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options, () => {
  // Write on the socket
 client.write('Hello server!');

  // Close socket
 client.destroy();
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('message was received', data);
});

client.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

client.on('close', function(){
  console.log('Connection closed!');
  });
```

I referred to the above code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tcp-socket).

But, I need more information.

Where can I provide the server's IP address in client side?

I need a small example for TCP client in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to specify IP in the option object in the host field, as described in the react-native-tcp-socket  doc.

> host - Host the socket should connect to. IP address in IPv4 format or 'localhost'. Default: 'localhost'.

For example:

```
const options = {
    port: 8443,
    host: "example.com", //give your IP address
    tls: true,
};

// Create socket
const client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options, () => {
  // Write on the socket
 client.write('Hello server!');

  // Close socket
 client.destroy();
});
```